# Запуск docker контейнера с определенным IP из Python

Tags: python, сеть, api, docker

Если запускать контейнер из консоли, то можно сделать это следующим образом

```
docker run -d --name iperf_srv --network mynet --ip 10.195.10.10 astotal/iperf3 -s
```

Как запустить контейнер на определенном IP используя python api?

Есть такой код, но как указать конкретный адрес я так и не смог разобраться

```
import docker 

doc = docker.from_env()
srv_pool=docker.types.IPAMPool(subnet='10.195.10.0/24',iprange='10.195.10.0/24')

srv_ipam=docker.types.IPAMConfig(pool_configs=[srv_pool])

doc.networks.create('uplink', driver='macvlan', options={'parent':'eth2.3200'},ipam=srv_ipam)

srv=doc.containers.run('astotal/iperf3', '-s', network='uplink', detach=True, name='iperf_server')
```

Контейнер запускается, но IP берется из пула.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучшее решение, которое смог придумать

```
srv = doc.containers.create('astotal/iperf3', '-s', detach=True, name='iperf_server')
doc.networks.get("uplink").connect(srv, ipv4_address="10.195.10.11")
srv.start()
```